# Вопрос по плагину IonTabs js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

У меня есть группа вкладок, на каждой из вкладок ещё одна группа вкладок (вложенные). Проблема в том, что по умолчанию вложенные вкладки закрыты и появляются только по клику заголовка на них. Как сделать так, чтобы по умолчанию всегда была открыта первая вложенная вкладка? 
Ссылка на плагин http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.tabs/#tabs|Product:Useful|Company:History